# GCMComminication Error the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, .net, networking, google-cloud-messaging

I'am getting error: "the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send  when using code below" exception is thrown on tRequest.GetResponse();

```
            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));

            int iRetryTime = 1;
            if (NotificationRetryTime > 10)
                iRetryTime = NotificationRetryTime - 10;


            string postData =
                 "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=" + iRetryTime.ToString() + "&delay_while_idle=0&data.message="
                  + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" +
                     regId + "";




            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

            dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();   //Get response from GCM server.

            tReader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            tResponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that our network team was blocking gcm at network level. After network configuration change i have successfully made gcm call.